# Error projecting from a grouped linq query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I have a database table that stores the following data regarding images:

```
public class EventImage
{

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int EventImageId { get; set; }

    public string EventImageFileExtension { get; set; }

    // Provided based on comments, but not used to reduce wasted bandwidth
    public virtual byte[]? EventImageFullSizeBytes { get; set; }

    // Provided based on comments, but not used to reduce wasted bandwidth
    public virtual byte[]? EventImageThumbnailBytes { get; set; }

    public int EventItemId { get; set; }
}
```

A typical DbSet is then used for querying:

```
public class WebAppContext : IdentityDbContext<WebAppRazorUser, ApplicationRole, int>
{
    public DbSet<EventImage> EventImages { get; set; }
}
```

My goal is to retrieve one image per (parent) event item but without the binary data being included.  Using different answers on SO I've pieced together the following:

```
var eventImages = context.EventImages.AsNoTracking()
                    // Filter to specific parent Id's
                    .Where(ei => uniqueEventIds.Contains(ei.EventItemId))
                    // Get only one image per parent
                    .GroupBy(img => img.EventItemId, (key, g) => g.OrderBy(img => img.EventImageId).FirstOrDefault()) 
                    // Project the image fields without the binary data
                    .Select(img => new 
                                {
                                img.EventImageId,
                                img.EventItemId,
                                img.EventImageFileExtension,
                                })
                                .ToList();
```

However its throwing an exception that I do not understand:

> KeyNotFoundException: The given key 'EmptyProjectionMember' was not present in the dictionary.
>
> System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.get_Item(TKey key)

If I remove the entire projection (`.Select(...)`) aspect, the first part of the query does return two images with all the fields populated, so I think that part is correct.  I'm not sure what the error is relating to though.

### Update

Swapping out certain elements provides strange results.

```
.Select(img => new object()) // Runs without an exception, but obviously doesn't actually give me what I need

.Select(img => new { }) // As above

.Select(img => new { Field1 = "Foo" }) // This fails with the same exception
```

### Update 2

If I create a list from the initial search and then project from that, it appears to work:

```
var eventImages = (context.EventImages.AsNoTracking()
                    .Where(ei => uniqueEventIds.Contains(ei.EventItemId))
                    .GroupBy(img => img.EventItemId, (key, g) => g.OrderBy(img => img.EventImageId).FirstOrDefault()))
                    .ToList() // Fixes the issue
                    .Select(img => new 
                                {
                                img.EventImageId,
                                img.EventItemId,
                                img.EventImageFileExtension,
                                });
```

Looking at the underlying class I believe the exception was caused by the property being virtual but would still appreciate an authoritative answer please.

Answer (score 4):

EF Core 6.0 / 7.0 query translation defect. But we should be tolerant, since translation of all LINQ query expression tree variations is a very complicated thing (if you try to do that yourself), so bugs/defects like this happen.

The workaround is to move the projection before the `FirstOrDefault` call (inside the `GroupBy` result selector), e.g.

```cs
.GroupBy(img => img.EventItemId, (key, g) => g
    .OrderBy(img => img.EventImageId)
    .Select(img => new 
    {
        img.EventImageId,
        img.EventItemId,
        img.EventImageFileExtension,
    })
    .FirstOrDefault()
)
```

Comment: That's helpful, thank you for clarifying the defect.  However, sadly when using your example the exception still occurs.

Comment: Hmm, I've tested it on both EFC 6.0 and 7.0.5 (with similar model, I guess one to many) and got the error with the original approach, and no error with the suggested workaround. Is this the real query or you have more operators after `GroupBy`? I've tested with `.ToList()` right after the above `GroupBy`. Can you provide [mre] (e.g. model, configuration and query that we can copy/paste and test)?

Comment: Thank you for your persistence.  This is the *exact* query as it appears in the code.  I'll update the question now to provide the missing information.

Comment: And yes sorry it is one-to-many.

Answer (score 1):

**Maybe your .net is old version. For your code I tried on .net7 efcore 7 it works fine**

Try this to see if it works

```cs
           var eventImages = context.EventImages.AsNoTracking()
           .Where(ei => uniqueEventIds.Contains(ei.EventItemId))
           .GroupBy(img => img.EventItemId) 
           .Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault())
           .Select(img => new 
               {
                   img.EventImageId,
                   img.EventItemId,
                   img.EventImageFileExtension,
               }).ToList();
```

Comment: I'm using .Net 7 with EF Core 7.0.5.  Your code also throws the same exception, however I'll update my question with new findings in a minute

Comment: @EvilDr so check your package that you included to the class, make sure it is `using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;` not `using System.Data.Entity;`.