# emptyprojectionmember' was not present in the dictionary

Tags: entity-framework-core, .net-7.0, ef-core-7.0

I have recently upgraded my application running Entity Framework Core 2.1.1 to Entity Framework Core 7.0.11.

The following part of code (C#) ran fine with the older version:

```cs
 var items = _dbContext.Contacts
                       .Where(c => (c.UserId == userId));

 items = qitems.GroupBy(c => c.ContactId).Select(c => c.First());

items = items.OrderBy(c => c.CompanyName);
items = items.Skip(skip).Take(pageSize).ToList();
```

// the above operation is performed against a database context

But after the upgrade, I get this error:

> System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: the given key 'emptyprojectionmember' was not present in the dictionary.

I was expecting that the same code should run as before.

Comment: Try EF Core 8, maybe they have fixed this issue. Grouping is a pain for EF developers. In EF Core 2.1 this query silently loaded whole table into the memory and grouped on the client side.

Comment: this is not fixed in EF Core 8 also.

Comment: @ElectricRouge, Not sure what is not fixed, it depends on your query. Try `items = qitems.GroupBy(c => c.ContactId).SelectMany(c => c.Take(1))`

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv my issue is similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76247570/error-projecting-from-a-grouped-linq-query. The workaround mentioned there works. But it still throws error in EF Core 8 if I try to project to a DTO after calling First().

Comment: So, Ivan proposed workaround. I don't know why they still not fixed this issue.