Dynamic LINQ sorting after grouping
We wrote a generic filterable repository in .NET 8 that should be able to accept a list of filters and a list of sorts, and apply them to any given entity.
Due to some business logic, we have a Task entity that needs to be grouped everytime it is filtered. The grouping 'eats' the sorts, and they never get applied, I checked the query that is executed. But we need to sort after the grouping, and then apply pagination.
The method looks like this:
public static (IQueryable Queryable, int TotalElements) BuildFilteredQuery(IQueryable queryable, List<FilterData> filters, List<SortData> sorts, int pageNo, int pageSize, bool distinct)
    {
        queryable = ApplyFilters(queryable, filters);
        queryable = ApplySorting(queryable, sorts);

        if (distinct)
        {
            queryable = queryable.GroupBy("new(CountSort)").Select("it.First()");
        }

        var totalElements = queryable.Count();

        if (pageSize != 0)
        {
            queryable = ApplyPaging(queryable, pageNo, pageSize);
        }

        return (queryable, totalElements);
    }

private static IQueryable ApplySorting(IQueryable queryable, List<SortData> sorts)
    {
        var sortingString = string.Join(", ", sorts.Select(s =>
            $"{s.PropertyName} {(s.Direction == ListSortDirection.Ascending ? "asc" : "desc")}"));

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sortingString))
        {
            queryable = queryable.OrderBy(sortingString);
        }

        return queryable;
    }

If we try to apply the sorting after the grouping, we get "The given key 'EmptyProjectionMember' was not present in the dictionary".

Seems like an EF issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77492560/emptyprojectionmember-was-not-present-in-the-dictionary

@Magnus Tried following the thread, but not sure how I would apply the workaround mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76247570/error-projecting-from-a-grouped-linq-query

Try doing the GroupBy without dynamic linq since it it constant and see if the workaround works.

@Magnus How do I rewrite it? queryable is not generic, so I can't use a lambda expression. I tried casting it before (since this operation happens only for one specific type), couldn't get it to work.

You have repostory, override method and do for this entity type apprpriate manipulations. I have cleared some time ago function which is workaround over EF Core issue, but it generates OrderBy by himself. So if it work for you al least for predefined sorted columns, I can rewrite it to accept your order definition.

@SvyatoslavDanyliv Sure I could write specific logic, but that wasn't the question. Thanks for the advice anyways
